# Finding book by genre using MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, user-interface

I am using a JFrame GUI with `mysql` and trying to get my program to find the entries with "Horror, Comedy, etc" when a user types the genre they want into the text field. It worked perfectly fine with my getAuthorByLastName but I cant seem to get it to work with genre and i think it has something to do with the setString(1, genre) portion of the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
selectBookByAuthorLName = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE LastName = ?");
selectBookByGenre = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Genre = ?");
    public List<Book> getBookByAuthorLastName(String name){
    List<Book> results = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try{
        selectBookByAuthorLName.setString(1, name);
        resultSet = selectBookByAuthorLName.executeQuery();
        results = new ArrayList<Book>();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            results.add(new Book(
                    resultSet.getString("ISBN"),
                    resultSet.getString("Title"),
                    resultSet.getString("LastName"),
                    resultSet.getString("FirstName"),
                    resultSet.getString("Genre"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("Price")));
            }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException){sqlException.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
        try{
            resultSet.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlException){sqlException.printStackTrace(); close();}
    }
    return results;
}

public List<Book> getBookByGenre(String genre){
    List<Book> results = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try{
        selectBookByGenre.setString(1, genre);


        resultSet = selectBookByGenre.executeQuery();
        results = new ArrayList<Book>();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            results.add(new Book(
                    resultSet.getString("ISBN"),
                    resultSet.getString("Title"),
                    resultSet.getString("LastName"),
                    resultSet.getString("FirstName"),
                    resultSet.getString("Genre"),
                    resultSet.getDouble("Price")));
            }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException){sqlException.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
        try{
            resultSet.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlException){sqlException.printStackTrace(); close();}
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Try to create statement within the methods and close them in finally block to avoid cursor problems in your DB.

Comment: Can you provide some sample row data from the database, along with the exact results you expect? _Can't get it to work_ means you are receiving an error or you are not getting the expected results?

Comment: "I cant seem to get it to work with genre" Please be more precise, what does that mean? Do you get an exception? Do you get an empty result list? What?